# Чтение только 1 байта из COM-порта на Bash

Tags: bash, com-порт

Есть задача прочитать первый пришедший байт из COM-порта на Bash и внести его в переменную.

В COM-порт постоянно идёт поток данных, но нужно, при обнаружении нужного байта, перестать слушать порт и внести его в переменную.

Если использовать `cat /dev/ttyACM1`, то прервать команду можно только убив процесс.

Comment: копируйте с помощью `dd bs=1 count=1 ...`. Правда не понимаю, почему вы строку "data here" состоящую из 9 байт, называете одним байтом

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте `head`:

```sh
$ head -c 1 /dev/tty/ACM1 > ./onebyte.bin
```